# Whats the difference between (a==1 || b==1) and ((a || b)==1)

Tags: javascript

Whats the difference between (a==1 || b==1) and ((a || b)==1)

this code block works right

```
 if(userName==="" || userAge==="" ){
addErrorBool(true);
return;}
```

but this one not

```
 if((userName || userAge)==="" ){
addErrorBool(true);
return;}
```

whats does the second one do?

Comment: In the second one, if `userName` is [falsy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy), it will use `userAge` and compare that to empty string. In this case, if `userName` is not populated and `userAge` is, it will compare `userAge` to `""` and fail your check.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

##### `(userName || userAge)===""` means:

- `(userName || userAge)`: if `userName` is truthy, use this value. Otherwise use `userAge`
- `===""`: compare whichever object was chosen above, and compare that this is a string with no contents.

##### `userName==="" || userAge===""` means:

- `userName===""`: compare `userName` to see if it is a string with no contents
- if it is, the result is true, otherwise:
- `userAge===""`: compare `userAge` to see if it is a string with no contents
- if it is, the result is true, otherwise the result is false

Answer (score 5):

`a || b` will evaluate to `a`, if `a` is truthy, otherwise it'll evaluate to `b`. So `((a || b)==1)` will take whichever value that was and compare it against 1.

For example

```
(0 || 5) == 1
// equivalent to
(5) == 1

(1 || 2) == 1
// equivalent to
(1) == 1
```

For what you want, use `.some` instead, if you want to keep things DRY.

```
if ([userName, userAge].some(val => val === '')) {
  addErrorBool(true);
  return;
}
```

And then you can add as many items to the array `.some` is called on that you want.